# Why does SQL query with GROUP BY produce more rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table:

```
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| id   | rev   | content                              |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    | 1     | ...                                  |
| 2    | 1     | ...                                  |
| 1    | 2     | ...                                  |
| 1    | 3     | ...                                  |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT id, MAX(rev) maxrev, content
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id;
```

I get:

```
+------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| id   | maxrev   | content                              |
+------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    |    3     | ...                                  |
| 2    |    1     | ...                                  |
+------+----------+--------------------------------------+
```

But if I remove the GROUP BY clause as follows:

```
SELECT id, MAX(rev) maxrev, content
FROM YourTable;
```

I get:

```
+------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| id   | maxrev   | content                              |
+------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    |    3     | ...                                  |
+------+----------+--------------------------------------+
```

This is counter-intuitive to me because of the expectation that a GROUP BY would reduce the number of results by eliminating duplicate values.  However, in the above case, introduction of the GROUP BY does the opposite.  Is this because of the MAX() function, and if so, how?

PS: The table is based on the SO question here: [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7745609/360840).  I was trying to understand the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745635/360840) to that question, and in the process, came across the above situation.

EDIT:

I got the above results on sqlfiddle.com using its MySQL 5.6 engine, with no customization/configuration.

Comment: @litelite No, if you don't use `GROUP BY`, it aggregates all the rows in the table without grouping.

Comment: @litelite Depends on your MySQL settings. Newer versions are more strict by default.

Comment: Because you're using a version of mySQL which extends the group by allowing you to aggregrate on zero or all of the fields in the select not aggregrated.. Current version of mySQL would throw a syntax error provided the extensions have  not been enabled.  Since you're not grouping by content it picks a single value and since all values are now the same they fall in to the same group.  When you eliminate all group by then the engine is fee to pick any id and content but only the max rev.

Comment: @tadman The new setting does the opposite, it mandates aggregation functions with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @tadman Ok, so that was just my MySQL being strict on me. Thanks!

Comment: Read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html especially: If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled...  because prior versions behaved this way.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I mean. The newer defaults make it complain if you fail to use a `GROUP BY` when using aggregate functions. Older versions didn't care by default, they'd just do *whatever*.

Comment: OK, looks like you're right, you get an error `Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause`

Comment: The first query gets a different error: `YourTable.content isn't in GROUP BY`

Comment: Ok I love the attention/comments and feedback on this question.  Great turnaround times and awesome information/discussion.  It should be noted that this, to my knowledge is somewhat unique to mySQL.  Most DB engines don't allow this.  Though I thought I encountered something like this in Sybase; but could be wrong..  Sybase groups by all non-aggregated fields if it's left off... Neat.

Comment: @xQbert I agree, this has been an education!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is utilizing your MAX() function dependent on your GROUP BY clause. So, for your first query, you are saying: Give me the maximum rev **for each id**, whereas the second is just saying Give me the maximum rev **in general**.

Thanks to xQbert:

This does **NOT** mean that you are getting the **row** with the max rev in the latter case. It will take values from anywhere in the selection to use for your id and content fields.

You can read more about how SQL handles the GROUP BY statement here:  [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: and the engine is free to choose any single value from ID and content since they are in the select.  (usually the first it encounters)

Comment: @xQbert You are right. I changed my table and input specific values in to the content field instead of "...".  The result for the second query (without the GROUP BY) is: `1, 3, 12`, when it should have been `1, 3, 13`.

Comment: Thanks @xQbert I've added it to my answer

Comment: Thank you @EastonBornemeier, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @Sabuncu it gets a little more messed up/hecktick when joins occur and subqueries because the value may be encountered before an order is executed thus the value is encountered may vary on different executions based on the query plan followed.  Best to ensure the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY  option is enabled imo.

Comment: @xQbert It's usually best just to specify a GROUP BY anyways, if possible by a primary key in order to ensure you are getting the whole row :)

Comment: I like the documentation on this: "In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause" it explains it well:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @xQbert In fact, the values in case of the first query (with the GROUP BY) are also incorrect.  The engine, as you said, just pulls random `content` value. Thanks for the link, these answers have been so useful.

Comment: @easttonbornemeier Booo!!! the opportunity to use mySQL extensions when you fully understand them can result in a performance gain!  For example if  I know all the values will be the same for the un grouped by columns, then the engine doesn't have the overhead of grouping them and pickign one DOESN'T matter.  since the engine doesn't have to group, then overhead is reduced.  This is a FEATURE one with purpose; but seldom used correctly; thus the reason the default was changed.  (End Commentary on the last line of your updated answer)

Comment: The above comment was for informational and comedic purposes only.  Any intent to inflame or cause harm to @EastonBornemeier was purely unintentional. ...  Cheers!  lack of group by... more like `how mySQL extends the standard group by`

Comment: NOOOOOOOOooooooooo........ :P glad people have a sense of humor around here... even if it is more warped than mine.

Answer (score 0):

This because you are using a version  previuos that mysql 5.7  ..these version allow the use of aggregated d  function and select column not in group by  ... this produce impredicatble result for the not aggregated  column .. in mysql 5.7 this beahvior is not allowed  ... you have an error   if you in select not aggregated  function not mentioned  in group by

the correct sintax is obviuosly the first

```
SELECT id, MAX(rev) maxrev, content
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: That's not what the new version requires. It prohibits non-aggregated columns when using `GROUP BY`, it doesn't require `GROUP BY` when using aggregation. Aggregating the entire table is standard SQL.

Comment: @Barmar mixing aggregated and non aggregated column references is not standard SQL

Comment: `MAX()` is an aggregation.

Comment: @Barmar yes `MAX` is an aggregate but they also select the non aggregated columns `id` and `content`

Comment: I understand that. But I don't think it has anything to do with the MySQL version. The `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode only affects what's allowed when you use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Ok but your original comment referred to standard SQL not whatever that option in MySql does.

Comment: @scaisEdge Thank you for pointing out the difference in behavior based on version of MySQL. Upvoted.

Comment: All 5.4.5 did I think was change the default of `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` from being `OFF` by default to allow group by extensions to be enabled to being `ON` by default (with regards to this behavior of course)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, MAX(rev) maxrev, content FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id;
```

When you run this, as there are 2 distinct ids in the table you get two rows in the result, one per id with the max value. The *grouping* happens on the id column.

```
SELECT id, MAX(rev) maxrev, content
FROM YourTable;
```

If you remove the *group by* clause, you only get one row in the result corresponding to the max value in the entire table. There is no *grouping* by id.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it.  I believe your answer is similar to Easton Bornemeier's.